# передать две и более модели через resttemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate

Подскажите, как передать две модели через resttemplate?
С одной моделью все работает, а вот как сразу две?)

```
restTemplate.postForObject(url, model_1,  String.class);


@PostMapping("/give")
public String getSort(@RequestBody Model_1 model_1, @RequestBody Model_2 model_2) {
    return manager.get(model_1, model_2);
}
```

Comment: Сделать класс data transfer object (DTO) и в нём будет несколько моделей/классов/моделей

Comment: @IharHulevich как бы хотелось без этого.... Думал может есть еще способы...